python celery beat[worker] process replenishes RAM
I have fastapi project with celery beat, that runs every 30minutes. It parses news from website rss apis and write to database.
Here's my celery configs:
configs.py
    ...
    # Celery configuration
    @property
    def CELERY_BROKER_URL(self) -> str:
        return f"redis://{self.REDIS_HOST}:{self.REDIS_PORT}/1"

    @property
    def CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND(self) -> str:
        return f"redis://{self.REDIS_HOST}:{self.REDIS_PORT}/2"

    @property
    def WS_MESSAGE_QUEUE(self) -> str:
        return f"redis://{self.REDIS_HOST}:{self.REDIS_PORT}/3"

    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE: dict = {
        "news-timer-scheduler": {
            "task": "news_parser",
            "schedule": 1800,  # 1800/60=30 minutes
        },
        "weather-timer-scheduler": {
            "task": "weather_parser",
            "schedule": 300.0,  # 300/60=5 minutes
        }
    }
    CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE: str = "default"

    # Force all queues to be explicitly listed in `CELERY_TASK_QUEUES` to help prevent typos
    CELERY_TASK_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES: bool = False
    CELERY_TIMEZONE: str = 'UTC'
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES: int = 120  # 2 minutes

celery_app.py
from celery import current_app as current_celery_app
from app.core.config import configs

def create_celery():
    celery = current_celery_app
    celery.config_from_object(configs, namespace="CELERY")
    celery.autodiscover_tasks(['app.celery.tasks'])
    return celery
celery_app = create_celery()

tasks.py
import asyncio
import gc
import psutil
from app.celery.celery_app import celery_app
from app.main import container

BATCH_SIZE = 10

@celery_app.task(name="news_parser")
def news_parser():
    print("====================RUNNING news_parser====================")
    process = psutil.Process()
    print(f"news_parser memory usage start:::::::: {process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2} MB")
    sites = asyncio.run(container.site_service().load_actives())  # Get list of active site IDs
        batch = sites[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]
        asyncio.run(container.news_timer_service().run_task(batch))
        del batch
        gc.collect()  # Collect garbage after processing each batch
    del sites
    gc.collect()
    print(f"news_parser memory usage end:::::::::: {process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2} MB")
    return {"news": "parsed"}

@celery_app.task(name="weather_parser")
def weather_parser():
    print("====================RUNNING weather_parser====================")
    process = psutil.Process()
    asyncio.run(container.weather_service().run_task())
    gc.collect()
    return {"weather": "parse"}


I used these command to run celery worker and beat:
celery -A app.celery.celery_app worker --loglevel=info --pool=solo &
celery -A app.celery.celery_app beat --loglevel=info --scheduler=celery.beat:PersistentScheduler


There are over 70 sites rss to parse and news_parser task takes a lot of time to run..
PROBLEM: RAM usage increases from time to time, and eventually the process replenishes RAM. At the end server freezes, and have to restart the server. How to clean up usage memory after process finished or give some limits, if reaches that limited memory do automatically restart celery worker.... ?
I try to run commands like below:
celery -A app.celery.celery_app worker --loglevel=info --max-memory-per-child=350000 --concurrency=3

celery -A app.celery.celery_app worker --loglevel=info --max-memory-per-child=350000 --max-tasks-per-child=3

but this uses next worker at the every time beat run.

in container.news_timer_service().run_task(batch) use gc.collect() and delete all variables after usage.
